# Kafka connect error when trying to use multiple listeners for kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka

I am deploying a confluent single-node so I am only manipulating `connect-standalone.properties` and `server.properties`.

I am trying to connect a remote producer to my local set-up so I have the following overrides in `server.properties`

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.20.23.105:9092,EXTERNAL://10.20.23.105:29092

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.20.23.105:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092

listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

After checking using Offset Explorer, I can see that Kafka is still working and I am successfully getting the remote stream. However, Connect fails upon trying to start the service.

```
[2023-02-13 10:26:02,992] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:85)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:79)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:73)
```

What are the possible fixes for this problem?
I have checked out this question [Kafka-connect, Bootstrap broker disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061369/kafka-connect-bootstrap-broker-disconnected), but since I am still using PLAINTEXT for my external listener, there shouldn't need to be any changes to the workers right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect isn't the problem. Start debugging with `kafka-console-producer`, for example.

1. `listeners` should not be hard-coded to any one IP.

   Use bind addresses to allow connection from all interfaces.

   ```
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092
   ```
2. For advertised listeners, "external" addresses should use a LAN IP. Not clear what your "localhost" listener is needed for here, since any connection that IP from that same machine would route back to itself, by default. More importantly, you don't need two ports opened for the same protocol-connection.
3. You've not shown your connect worker properties, but if it is running on an external machine, make sure there is no firewall interfering with the connection, and that you are using the correct IP/hostname and ports.

Comment: Messing around with Connect's configs made the issue worse so I reverted everything and just made those suggested changes to server.properties.

Works great now, writing both to the topic and the psqldb connected to it.